# How to get the last record ID?

Tags: 7

I'm inserting values using `user_save()`. I have used this, but it is returning the wrong values.

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM <table name>
```

How can I get the ID of the last record `user_save()`inserted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you acquire the user object by using its return value and then you read the uid, which is also the unique value that belongs to the database row:

```
$user = user_save($user_obj);
$id = $user->uid;
```

Comment: No problem of course.